# Add a QLabel to QVBoxLayout at runtime but It doesn't work in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I want to add widgets to `QVBoxLayout` at runtime.But It doesn't work when I use `addWidget` method of that layout.Then I think whether a method used to refresh layout or application is needed,but others' code those don't need it have a good representation.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from socket import *
from collections import deque


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Chatting(QWidget) :
    _name = None

    serverAddr = ('localhost', 20123)
    client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

    def __init__(self,name,):
        super(Chatting, self).__init__()

        self._name = name

        self.setWindowTitle('Chatting')
        self.setFixedWidth(645)
        self.setFixedHeight(445)

        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrollWidget = QWidget()
        self.scrollWidget.setFixedWidth(645)
        self.scrollWidget.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.verticalLayoutTop = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self. scrollWidget.setLayout(self.verticalLayoutTop)
        scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)

        send = QWidget()
        horizontalLayoutBottom = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.contentEdit = QLineEdit()
        horizontalLayoutBottom.addWidget(self.contentEdit)
        self.sendButton = QPushButton('Send')
        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.send)
        horizontalLayoutBottom.addWidget(self.sendButton)
        send.setLayout(horizontalLayoutBottom)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(scrollArea)
        mainLayout.addWidget(send)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        clientThread = ClientThread(client=self.client,parent=self)
        self.connect(clientThread,clientThread.signal,self.writeToMessageList)
        clientThread.start()

    def send(self):
        self.client.sendto(self._name + ' say:' + self.contentEdit.text().toUtf8(),self.serverAddr)
        self.contentEdit.setText('')

    def writeToMessageList(self,message):
        print message
        '''
           I can get data here.
           So errors happened at the following two line.
        '''
        messageLabel = QLabel(message)
        self.scrollWidget.layout().addWidget(messageLabel)

class ClientThread(QThread) :

    BUFSIZE = 1024

    _client = None

    def __init__(self,client,parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self._client = client
        self.signal = SIGNAL("signal")

    def run(self):
        self.receive()

    def receive(self):

        while True:
            data,addr = self._client.recvfrom(self.BUFSIZE)
            self.emit(self.signal,data)

if __name__ == '__main__':

     dialog = Chatting(name='Little pig')
     dialog.show()

     app.exec_()
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `self.verticalLayoutTop` directly? That said, if you are writing a chat application, you may be better served using a text edit box and adding a line of text, rather than creating new labels for each message.

Comment: @JonHarper Yeah,I have tried calling `self.verticalLayoutTop`,but It doesn't work,so I tried to call `self.scrollWidget.layout()`. And now I just wanna write a simple demo,so I used `QLabel` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

```
self.scrollWidget.setFixedWidth(645)
self.scrollWidget.setFixedWidth(400)
```

Let layout control widget size.

Another problem is `QVBoxLayout(self)`! If you pass widget as layout constructor parameter this immediately sets layout to given widget, so in your case `Chatting`. From that point this layout can't be moved to other widget (You should have some warning in logs).
So fix it like this:

```
def __init__(self,name,):
    super(Chatting, self).__init__()

    self._name = name

    self.setWindowTitle('Chatting')
    self.setFixedWidth(645)
    self.setFixedHeight(445)

    scrollArea = QScrollArea()
    scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
    scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
    self.scrollWidget = QWidget()
    self.verticalLayoutTop = QVBoxLayout()
    self. scrollWidget.setLayout(self.verticalLayoutTop)
    scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)

    send = QWidget()
    horizontalLayoutBottom = QHBoxLayout(send)
    self.contentEdit = QLineEdit()
    horizontalLayoutBottom.addWidget(self.contentEdit)
    self.sendButton = QPushButton('Send')
    self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.send)
    horizontalLayoutBottom.addWidget(self.sendButton)

    mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    mainLayout.addWidget(scrollArea)
    mainLayout.addWidget(send)

    clientThread = ClientThread(client=self.client,parent=self)
    self.connect(clientThread,clientThread.signal,self.writeToMessageList)
    clientThread.start()
```

Comment: I realize that `QVBoxLayout(self)` is wrong by your explanation.And I tried your solution,but It doesn't work.At the same time,I can't find any errors in  logs.I also find that when I remove `self.scrollWidget.setFixedWidth(645)
self.scrollWidget.setFixedWidth(400)`,the new view is same with old one.I don't know the reason.

Comment: can you review Qt logs? I'm pretty sure there will be some information what is wrong.

Comment: There won't be a log message. He doesn't create `mainLayout` and set it as the layout for `self` until later. The vertical layout is reparented immediately, so there's never a "two layout" issue.

Comment: I use PyCharm and I don't know how to view log.I only know there are some informations in `Run `area.And no error shows here.This is my first attempt of python,so I don't know many skills.

Comment: Oh,I have found something important.I have changed `writeToMessageList` method and added this line:`print self.scrollWidget.children()`.And the output is as following:`[<PyQt4.QtGui.QVBoxLayout object at 0x7f3a2792ca68>, <PyQt4.QtGui.QLabel object at 0x7f3a2792ce90>]`.Maybe the `QLabel` has been added,but it didn't show?

Comment: I add same code in `__init__` method,and it works well.The part I have changed is `self.verticalLayoutTop = QVBoxLayout()
    label = QLabel('hello')
    self.verticalLayoutTop.addWidget(label)
    self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.verticalLayoutTop)
    scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)`                                                                 So whether the sequences of codes were wrong?

Comment: I learned from the document([PyQT document,at the location that explains `setWidget` method](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/doc/html/qscrollarea.html)) that if we add widgets to `QScrollArea`after calling `setWidget()` method of `QScrollArea`.The widgets we add will not show.Then what can we do for this problem,or is there another widget to archive same effect?